# JavaFX Media Player Only Playing One Second of MP3

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to get a mp3 file to play on JavaFX's MediaPlayer from a downloaded file. It is really weird because when I run my code, I hit the play button and it only plays for a second. When I hit the rewind button though, then the mp3 plays. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

I have tried using the URL from where I got the mp3 from, but I get an error saying that https protocol is not supported.

Here is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import static java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile;

public class JavaFXApplet extends Application{

    //private static final String MEDIA_URL = "https://www.bensound.com/bensound-music/bensound-summer.mp3";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Media media = new Media("file:///Users/mycomputer/Downloads/bensound-summer.mp3");
        //Media media = new Media(MEDIA_URL);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        Button playButton = new Button(">");
        playButton.setOnAction(e -> {mediaPlayer.play();});

        Button pauseButton = new Button("||");
        pauseButton.setOnAction(e-> mediaPlayer.pause());

        Button rewindButton = new Button("<<");
        rewindButton.setOnAction(e -> mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.ZERO));

        Slider slVolume = new Slider();
        slVolume.setPrefWidth(150);
        slVolume.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        slVolume.setMinWidth(30);
        slVolume.setValue(50);
        mediaPlayer.volumeProperty().divide(100);

        HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(playButton, pauseButton, rewindButton, new Label("Volume"), slVolume);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(mediaView);
        pane.setBottom(hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 650, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Player");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(windowEvent -> {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

}
```

I am using a Mac with IntelliJ, and I have tried using Eclipse as well without any success.

I'm open to any suggestions on how to get this to work properly or how to get the URL to work.

Comment: 1. I couldn't reproduce "it only plays for a second",  it works properly in Win env. (I changed only the path ""file:///e:/bensound-summer.mp3""). 2. Do you want to play "online" or downloaded file ?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the problem on Windows 10 with JavaFX 13.0.1. Both the `https` and `file` URLs work.

Comment: @Oleksandr Well, I am trying to get it to play either way. If I can get it to work with the https, that would be better. Could it be my version of either IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Comment: @Perdue Well, IDE version (IntelliJ or Eclipse) doesn't make any sense. The only idea I've got rn -> pls try to declare mediaPlayer as a class member.

Comment: @Oleksandr What do you mean by declaring mediaPlayer as a class member? Do you mean to take it out of the Start class? I tried that and that didn't seem to help.

Comment: @Perdue Take it out of the start method. Pls. make sure that mediaPlayer is not collected by GC.
`public class JavaFXApplet extends Application {

 private final Media media = new Media("file:///e:/bensound-summer.mp3");
 private final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

 @Override
 public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
  ...
 }
`

Comment: @Oleksandr Just tried that and it didn't work. Still did the same thing. Could it be the jdk version I'm using? I'm not using the latest version, but it's still 1.8.

Comment: @Perdue I'm running Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10). Could the file getting the lock by any different app?

Comment: @Oleksandr Not that I am aware of. I haven't played it in another app other than the one I am working on.

Comment: @Perdue did you try to run std. example? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/EmbeddedMediaPlayer.zip

Comment: @Oleksandr I haven't. I basically gave up since it seemed to work for you just fine in a Windows environment. I am thinking that this might be a Mac bug, and my professor uses Windows so it might be fine for him. Thank you though for all of your help.

Comment: @Oleksandr I actually figured out the solution! I'll answer my own question for you to see what I did. Thanks again for trying to help me figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up figuring this out on my own after some research.

I found this JDK bug post that sounded just like my issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138754

What I ended up doing was adding this into my code to get my mediaPlayer to work:
mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);

I hope that this will help out someone with the same issue someday.

Comment: nice investigation